# Default page layout changes when I push a new layout

Tags: profile, page-layout, salesforcedx

I have added a new page layout. When I create a new scratch org and run a push, all profiles will have the new page layout even though I haven't specified it on any of the profiles.

Is there a way to keep the default page layout for all the profiles. (Note I will modify one of the profiles to have the new page layout). Preferrably without having to maintain a copy for all the other profiles just to set the page layout to what should be the default.